# Запуск бинарника из Apache

Tags: apache, cgi

Подскажите, как настроить Apache 2 на запуск скриптов через программу.
Писал в конфиге:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-msl .msl
ScriptAlias /msl/ "www/"

<Directory "/www/">
  AllowOverride None
  Options ExecCGI
</Directory>
Action application/x-httpd-msl "/msl/msl"
```

Не работает. Нужно запустить бинарник при запросе любого .msl файла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddType application/x-httpd-msl .msl
AddHandler application/x-httpd-msl .msl
#AddHandler cgi-script .msl

ScriptAlias /msl/ "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/"
#
<Directory "/usr/local/apache/cgi-bin/">
  AllowOverride None
  Options +ExecCGI
  order deny,allow
  allow from all
</Directory>
Action application/x-httpd-msl "/msl/msl-fl"
```